# vector of vectors push_back

Tags: c++, vector, process, push-back, multi-level

I'm designing a multilevel queue process simulator in C++ but I've got a problem when trying to implement several queues (my queues are vectors).So,
"multilevel" is a 4 elements array (not vector). Inside each of those elements there is a vector (type t_PCB).

```
vector<vector<t_PCB>> multilevel[4];
```

My question is: How can i insert an element at the end of one these 4 `t_PCB` vectors? Thank you in advance.

I've tried the code line below but it doesn't work (**error**: not matching member function for call 'push_back')

```
multilevel[0].push_back(p); //where "p" is a t_PCB object
```

The line from above can not be used when talking about "multilevel" because this array only accepts arguments type: vector < t_PCB >

So, as I ask at the beginning: how can I push an object type "t_PCB" inside "multilevel"?

Comment: multilevel is not a "4 elements vector" but an array of a vector containing vectors of t_PCB

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By doing this:

```
vector<vector<t_PCB> > multilevel[4];
```

You declare an *array* of four zero-sized `vectors`, each of which can contain objects of type `vector<t_PCB>`. What you probably wanted to do is rather:

```
vector<vector<t_PCB> > multilevel(4);
//                               ^^^
```

This will instantiate a vector of four default-initialized objects of type `vector<t_PCB>`. Then, you can just do:

```
multilevel[size].push_back(p);
```

Notice, though, that vector indices (like array indices) are zero-based, so `size` must be less than the size of the vector.

In the above expression, the sub-expression `multilevel[size]` returns a reference to the `size`-th vector inside `multilevel`, and on that vector you are then invoking the member function `push_back(p)`, which appends element `p` to it.

Comment: this code --> multilevel[size].push_back(p); 

only works if multilevel is declared as follows;
vector <t_PCB> multilevel[4];

Comment: @jafm92 Look carefully. You need to change the `[4]` to `(4)`. You were declaring an array of vectors of vectors. Andy is showing you how to declare just a vector of vectors. On the other hand, `vector <t_PCB> multilevel[4]` is an array of vectors. You need to decide which one you want.

Comment: @jafm92 It seems from the way you're describing it that you want a vector of four vectors. In which case, do exactly as Andy has said.

Comment: @sftrabbit Thank You, i'm trying to implement a vector of 4 vectors. I thought that (4) was just a typing mistake. What is the difference between [4] and (4)? thank you (again)

Comment: @jafm92 Please read this answer - he explains it fully. The `[4]` is declaring an *array* of vectors of vectors. So you have an array of four vectors of vectors. Instead you just want a vector of FOUR vectors. The `(4)` is passing an argument to the constructor of `std::vector`, telling it to initialise to 4 elements. **Alternatively**, a `vector<t_PCB> multilevel[4]` would also work, which is an array of four vectors.

Comment: @jafm92: Sorry for the late answer. The difference is that `T x[4]` is used to create an array called `x` of 4 elements each of which has type T. The `T x(4)` constructs *one* object called `x` of type `T` and passes `4` as an argument to its constructor. Since, in your case, `T` is `vector<vector<t_PCB>>`, you are calling the constructor of `vector` which accepts its size as an argument, and by passing `4` you tell the constructor that you want your vector to contain 4 elements of type `vector<t_PCB>`. Hope this clarifies

Comment: @sftrabbit: Thank you for trying to help, I was busy and could not answer myself - I appreciate it

Comment: @AndyProwl: I understand. My new problem is that when trying to declare like this (as a member variable of the class) "vector< vector <t_PCB> > multilevel(4);" inside my class I get an error.

Comment: @jafm92: OK, as a class member variable you cannot use that syntax. Either do what sftrabbit suggested (`vector<t_PCB> multilevel[4]`), or just declare it as `vector< vector <t_PCB> > multilevel;` and use constructor initialization lists to pass the value `4` to the constructor of `multilevel`.

Answer (score 21):

Declaring a two dimensional vector is similar to declaring an array. You can also use it in same way...

```
vector<vector<int> > vec;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    vector<int> row;
    vec.push_back(row);
}

vec[0].push_back(5);
cout << vec[0][0] << endl;
```

Answer (score 5):

You are creating a array of `vector<vector<t_PCB>>` instead of a single object.

I think the right way to do what you want is:

```
vector<vector<t_PCB>> multilevel(4);
multilevel[0].push_back(p)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a vector instead of array:

```
std::vector< std::vector<t_PCB>> multilevel(4); // 2 dim array, 1st dim is 4
```

and then you can [push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) at the end of the vector indexed with `WHICH` this way:

```
multilevel[WHICH].push_back(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

And just to put it out there, to access the vector of vectors:

```
multilevel[outer][inner]
```

where `outer` will return the vector at that index and further indexing 
with `inner` will return the `t_PCB` object. You could also replace the array-style indexing with the [.at()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) function for bounds checks.

Answer (score -1):

```
vector<vector<int>> vec; // declare 2D vector

    for (int i=0; i<=3; i++) {
        vector<int> row;  // create a row vector which adds a row to vec
        for (int j=0; j<=4; j++) {
            row.push_back(j*10); // push elements 0,10,20,30,40 to row 
        }
        vec.push_back(row); // add this row to vec
        // Repeat this procedure 4 times to make a 4*5 2D vector
    }

    cout<<"output is "<<vec[2][4]; // output is 40
```